# Extracting date from a string throwing error

Tags: javascript, regex

The Following code

```
'\/\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}\/'g.exec('<span style=\"color:green\">291</span> days until expiry on 25/11/2017')
```

Is expected to give out `"25/11/2017"` but it is giving a browser console error "Unexpected identifier". Any idea why and how to fix it?

Comment: General comment: Use an HTML parser for better results.

Comment: Curious why you are attempting to use `RegExp` on an `html` string? How do you get string?

Comment: @guest271314 My guess is OP is trying to get the date from the **string**. Even if it is read of DOM, the date is not wrapped in element so it cannot be extracted using `textContent`/`innerHTML` properties. It has to be extracted using regex/substring.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen ^^^. HTML parser will not help in this case. If the HTML is `<span style=\"color:green\">291</span> days until expiry on <span>25/11/2017</span>`, it'll help.

Comment: @Tushar I agree, but I assumed that the OP took the fragment from an HTML document.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen As explained, in my previous comment, even if HTML is read from DOM, as the date is not wrapped in it's own tag e.g. `<span class="date">25/11/2017</span>`, it cannot be extracted by DOM methods.

Comment: @Tushar _"Even if it is read of DOM, the date is not wrapped in element so it cannot be extracted using textContent/innerHTML properties."_? `document.querySelector("span[style^=color]").nextSibling.textContent` or iterate `#text` nodes.

Comment: @guest271314 Please check [this demo](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/ctg5jdv0/) which gives `textContent` with your code. Now, this gives complete text(not just date) and to extract date from it, you'll need to use regex/substring methods.

Comment: @Tushar Yes, though "the date is not wrapped in element so it cannot be extracted using textContent/innerHTML properties." is not entirely correct.

Comment: @guest271314 What I mean is, the date cannot be extracted by _just_ using DOM methods.

Comment: Yes, `DOM` methods can be used to extract date. The `RegExp` can also be simplified to `var date = text.replace(/[^\d\/]/g, "");` https://jsfiddle.net/ctg5jdv0/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is here `/'g`.

The regex should not be wrapped in string when using in literal form. It should be surrounded by forward slashes, and not backward slashes.

```js
var date = /\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}/g.exec('<span style=\"color:green\">291</span> days until expiry on 25/11/2017');
console.log(date);
```

Note that as the backslashes are escaped in your regex, passing the regex as it is to the `RegExp` constructor will not produce the expected result.

Not recommended, but just in case, if you want to use later syntax, escape the backslashes twice.

```
new RegExp('\\d{2}\\/\\d{2}\\/\\d{4}', 'g').exec('...
```

Also, note that `RegExp#exec` returns **array**.